# Checking if my second hand Android phone is safe: am I right?

Tags: root-access, security, rom-flashing, custom-roms, factory-reset

First of all, I know that this question has been asked before, but I'd like to hear if the way I'm checking my "new" phone is safe. I know I'm probably overthinking things, but I just would like to know.

So, to get to the point: it's a second hand, but very recent OPPO (2021) running ColorOS 11.1 (which I was able to update to the latest July security patch).

- I did a factory reset
- I did a reset via Recovery mode
- "OEM Unlock" is OFF
- Root checker apps say it's NOT rooted
- Safety Net status: passed
- The phone is Play Protect certified
- I'm able to install banking apps and activate Google Pay
  The official ROM for this phone isn't available online (I contacted support), so I can't reflash it myself.

The last time I used Android was before 2016, when it still was possible to install tracking software that could survive a reset... and as it's my first second hand phone, I'm just overthinking things, but want to know.

So: with all the info above, is it possible that the previous owner flashed malicious software that could survive the resets I did? Or is it no longer possible on Android nowadays (considering the info above)?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You did everything you could do to verify the phone firmware is genuine. Unfortunately there is still a chance that the OS has been manipulated, but considering the age of the phone the chance is very low is this had happened using an exploit. But I am not sure how your device would behave it it had been bootloader unlocked, modified and then relocked.

Comment: Thanks for your input, @Robert!